# Regulation of the distance between the first verse and the previous paragraph using `verse`

Tags: spacing, verse

The insertion of poetry in a given prose text using the ambient `verse` introduces a distance between the first verse and the previous paragraph, as well as between the last verse and the following paragraph.

[image]

Is it possible to regulate these two gaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I leave to you setting the separation that suits you as the value of `\topsep`. Note that `\partopsep` is added when a blank line precedes `verse`, so you may want to set it instead or together with `\topsep`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\verse
  {\itemsep}
  {\topsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt \itemsep}
  {}{}

\begin{document}

In the beginning, when God created the heavens and the
earth, the earth was a formless wasteland, and darkness covered
the abyss, while a mighty wind swept over the waters.

\begin{verse}
  La vispa Teresa gridava sospesa: \\
  l'ho presa, l'ho presa, la vispa Teresa! \\
  Gridava sospesa: L'ho presa, l'ho presa, \\
  La vispa Teresa! Grida sospesa
\end{verse}

Then God said, Let there be light, and there was light. God
saw how good the light was. God then separated the light from
the darkness.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg. I noticed that this method does not works with documentclass memoir, and I can't figure why...

Comment: @PaoloPolesana Because `memoir` redefines `verse`? ;-) Since I cannot read minds (yet), I went with a standard class. For `memoir`, load `xpatch` instead of `etoolbox` and use `\xpatchcmd` instead of `\patchcmd`.

Comment: Perfect! I did not mention memoir just for ignorance: a detail I thought unimportant . Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own `myverse` environment which adjusts the vertical spacing above/below the verse:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paper=a5paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{mdframed,xkeyval}

\newlength{\mvskipabove}
\newlength{\mvskipbelow}
\makeatletter
\define@key{myverse}{skipabove}{\setlength{\mvskipabove}{#1}}
\define@key{myverse}{skipbelow}{\setlength{\mvskipbelow}{#1}}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{myverse}[1][]
  {\setkeys{myverse}{skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=0pt,#1}%
   \begin{mdframed}[
     leftmargin=1.5em,
     linewidth=0pt,
     innertopmargin=\mvskipabove,
     innerbottommargin=\mvskipbelow]}
  {\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

In the beginning, when God created the heavens and the
earth, the earth was a formless wasteland, and darkness covered
the abyss, while a mighty wind swept over the waters.

\begin{verse}
  La vispa Teresa gridava sospesa: \\
  l'ho presa, l'ho presa, la vispa Teresa! \\
  Gridava sospesa: L'ho presa, l'ho presa, \\
  La vispa Teresa! Grida sospesa
\end{verse}

Then God said, Let there be light, and there was light. God
saw how good the light was. God then separated the light from
the darkness.

\begin{myverse}
  La vispa Teresa gridava sospesa: \\
  l'ho presa, l'ho presa, la vispa Teresa! \\
  Gridava sospesa: L'ho presa, l'ho presa, \\
  La vispa Teresa! Grida sospesa
\end{myverse}

Then God said, Let there be light, and there was light. God
saw how good the light was. God then separated the light from
the darkness.

\begin{myverse}[skipabove=5\baselineskip,skipbelow=1pt]
  La vispa Teresa gridava sospesa: \\
  l'ho presa, l'ho presa, la vispa Teresa! \\
  Gridava sospesa: L'ho presa, l'ho presa, \\
  La vispa Teresa! Grida sospesa
\end{myverse}

Then God said, Let there be light, and there was light. God
saw how good the light was. God then separated the light from
the darkness.

\end{document}
```

The above `myverse` environment is actually an `mdframed` environment, with some default options to mimic a regular `verse`. However, you can add to these defaults, or specify them as optional arguments to `myverse` in the form of `skipabove=<len>` and/or `skipbelow=<len>`, where `<len>` is some length.

Comment: Thanks @Werner, this method works with memoir class also. I just noticed that if you put skipabove and skipbelow to zero, you obtain a minimum skip between the upper and lower paragraph and the verses. Curiously the gap below is slightly greater than the skip below. Thus, the gaps are under control, unless a minimum default.